# How do I import Three.js into my Nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

I want to import modules in examples folder in THREE.js such as OBJLoader into my Nuxt Project.

I can import main folder of THREE, but error occurs when trying to import modules in examples folder.

Tried these steps in official docs.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

I'm getting error below

SyntaxError
Unexpected token {

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
export default{
}
</script>
```

here are my github repository
https://github.com/ksuhara/threejs-test

Comment: What is the context for that error message? Where are you seeing it? What part of your code is it referring to?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this at all ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-jmdmd

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761761/i-cant-use-third-party-components-in-nuxt-js-vue-js

Comment: Did you find the reason why you were getting this error? Im facing the same issue for a while, and apparently this is the only place that talks about it. Could you update the question, or maybe answer it?

Answer (score 8):

Finally I could find what was wrong.

Well, it has to do with nuxt building system. When using third parts libs, you should add them into `nuxt.config.js` `bild->transpile` array so it can be included as a dependency with Babel.

`transpile: [
  "three"
]`

Ref: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#transpile

Comment: Thank you so much ! Finally got it working, was stuck with this for days. They should really mention this in the offical nuxt guide in the plugin section.

Comment: This worked for me, just a quick note for those who don't find it obvious: the `transpile` array property has to go WITHIN the `build` object property in your nuxt.config.js file. I blindly copied what was in the answer and put it in my file, which obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Threejs must be run on the client side so enclosed the component with `<client-only>` tag and loaded it dynamically with `const MyComponent = () => import('~/path/to/MyComponent.vue');` but now I am getting the error on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to do it like this!

```
<template>
    <div>
        <client-only>
            <threejs-component />
        </client-only>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    components: {
        ThreejsComponent: process.browser ? () => import('~/path/to/ThreejsComponent.vue') : null
    }
}
</script>
```

inside ThreejsComponent.vue are all the threejs imports